# Shach on orach chayim

Tags: shulchan-aruch

I came accross a Magen Avrohom [או״ח תמ״ז ס״ק י״ג](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.447.13) that quotes a Shach that he says is בגליון does anyone know what he might be referring to?

Comment: We don't have the Shach's commentary on Orach Chaim

Comment: But from friedman shulchan aruch they say its the גליון באו״ח it sounds like they have access to it? Do you know such a thing existed that we don’t  have anymore or are you assuming?

Comment: Right, I saw in another place in mine that we don't have it.

Comment: You saw in your shulchan aruch that we dont have it?

Answer (score 3):

I saw in the ArtScroll book ׳Later Achronim׳ that the מג״א does quote a ש״ך on או״ח, more specifically on hilchos pesach, which we don't have.

Answer (score 3):

The Pri Megadim (Siftei Da'at) understands the Shach in his commentary to [Yoreh Deah 103:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%92_%D7%90) to be referencing his own commentary on Orach Chaim. If so, the Magen Avraham may still have had it, though it is not currently extant.

This is also noted on the [Shach's Wikipedia page.](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F)

Comment: It's not 100% clear that the Pri Megadim is reading the acronym right. The shach may just be referring to the ShA or some particular commentary there. Indeed it's unlikely that hed only ever cross references it once if it was already written.

Comment: True, but if the Magen Avraham is also quoting the commentary, it's far more likely to exist.

Comment: if it was that widely available it's also that much more surprising that we don't have it. Still pretty likely to be either a different book named ש"כ or a misreference of some sort. This is like the Yerushalmi on Kodshim. It would be a wonderfully satisfying answer to many stirot and missing references, but that doesn't make it likely.

Comment: "Exists" does not mean widely available.

Comment: wide is relative. For the Magen Avraham on central Poland to happen to have had the only manuscript would be an amazing coincidence

Comment: שם הגדולים מערכת גדולים אות ש [י] מהר"ר שבתי הכהן
בסוף ש"ך י"ד כתב המגיה שהיה לו להרב חיבור גדול על התלמוד והפוסקים.

Comment: Before this gets too involved, note how apparently the Shach and Magen Avraham met in person at one point. http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%A8